# Can Nivo Slider change slides without any effects?

Tags: media, javascript

I am trying to make the Nivo Slider module slide in between pictures without any effects. Is this possible from the Drupal admin section? Do I need to dive into code to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select fade and make the fade occur in 1ms, then it will appear to change slides without any effects.